# Receiving any array type in function arguments

Tags: arrays, go

I just started playing with Go. I started creating a function that accepts an array of integers and returning the chunks of that array. To see what I mean, here is that program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    a:= []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,2, 231, 521,21, 51}

    c:=chunks(a[:], 3)
    fmt.Println(c) // [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [2 231 521] [51]]
}

func chunks(a []int, size int) [][]int{
    var f float64 = float64(len(a)) / float64(size)
    size_of_wrapper := int(math.Ceil(f))
    i := 0
    j := 0
    twoD := make([][]int, size_of_wrapper )

    for i < len(a) {
        if i + size < len(a) {
            twoD[j] = make([]int, size)
            twoD[j] = append(a[i:i+size])
            i = i + size
            j++
        } else {
                if i + size == len(a){
                i++
            } else {
                twoD[j] = make([]int, 1)
                    twoD[j] = append(a[len(a)-1:])
                i++
            }

        }
    }

    return twoD 
}
```

Now, I have a question. Can I turn this function to be able to receive an array that has strings in it or any other types? Also, can I set to return that same type at the end? In this case, I return an array of arrays that contain only integer values.

I seem to really struggle to find the solution to this problem. One of the posts that I have read recommended to use interface type for this kind of job. Is that the only one?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `[]int` is a _slice_, not an _array_.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I turn this function to be able to receive an array that has strings in it or any other types?
>   Also, can I set to return that same type at the end? I

Unfortunately the Go programming language does not have generics. AFAIK Go will have generics in the next 2.0 release so right now you mainly have 3 maybe 4 options.

### 1. Using the `[]interface{}` type

Your function declaration will look something like this.

```
func chunks(a []interface{}, size int) [][]interface{}
```

Using this approach will imply some [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15).

### 2. Using the [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package

The definition will look the same but this time in your implementation, instead of using the type assertion technique you will use the reflect package to determine your type and retrieve values. Remember you will [pay a reasonable cost](http://www.jerf.org/iri/post/2945) using this approach.

### 3. Using some unsafe.Pointer magic.

You could use this generic pointer type and do some pointer arithmetic in a C spirit way.

```
func chunks(a unsafe.Pointer, len uintptr, size uintptr) unsafe.Pointer
```

I know if you search Go does not ***oficially*** support doing pointer arithmetic but you can ***fake*** it using tricks like.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    vals := []int{10, 20, 30, 40}
    start := unsafe.Pointer(&vals[0])
    size := unsafe.Sizeof(int(0))
    for i := 0; i < len(vals); i++ {
        item := *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(start) + size*uintptr(i)))
        fmt.Println(item)
    }
}
```

### 4. Try using [go generate](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/generate/) in your building phase

You can find [more information](https://blog.golang.org/generate) on how to generate go code base on what types you provide.

Answer (score 1):

Because Go does not yet have the generics, the options are to use reflection or to duplicate code for each type.  Here's how to use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package:

```
// chunkAny slices a into size chunks and puts result in cp. 
// The variable cp must be pointer to slice of a's type.
func chunkAny(a interface{}, size int, cp interface{}) {
    av := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    cv := reflect.ValueOf(cp).Elem()
    cv.SetLen(0) // reset length in case backing array allocated
    i, j := 0, size
    for j < av.Len() {
        cv.Set(reflect.Append(cv, av.Slice(i, j)))
        i += size
        j += size
    }
    cv.Set(reflect.Append(cv, av.Slice(i, av.Len())))
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
a := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
var b [][]string
chunkAny(a, 3, &b)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ozNp8diySkJ).

Comment: I liked this solution and the reference to the `reflect` package. I will definitely look into it. Somehow I have a feeling that to do any useful stuff with arrays, there is a huge ceremony around it. This problem would be one example. Can you tell me, is there some package that has all those array methods in them so I would not have to reinvent the wheel every time I operate on arrays?

Comment: The [Slice Tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks) wiki page shows how to perform many common slice operations in one or two lines of Go code.  I don't know of a library that provides chunking as in this question.